# Create new Vector from old Vector?

Tags: vector, rust

I was wondering how to create a new Vector from an old Vector, and insert elements into it.

```
let vec1 = vec!["Hello", "world!"];
let vec2 = Vec::newFrom(vec1).insert(1, " ");
```

What method/function can I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `clone` to make a copy of the original `Vec`.

```
let vec1 = vec!["Hello", "world!"];
let mut vec2 = vec1.clone();
vec2.insert(1, " ");
```